# Matrices $A$ and $B$ so that $AB=I$ but $BA \ne I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

My teacher was giving a lesson on matrices today, and he mentioned that, given two square matrices (of the same dimensions) $A$ and $B$, in order to determine if $A=B^{-1}$, we have to make sure that both $AB=I$ and $BA=I$, as matrix multiplication is not commutative.

However, it seems that given $A$, there is only one solution for $B$ to the equation $AB=I$.

Can someone show an example of two matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $AB=I$ but $BA \ne I$? Or prove that this not possible?

Comment: It is not possible, if $AB=I$ then $BA=I$

Comment: @philip could you prove that?

Comment: [Duplicate of this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3852/81360)

Comment: If you relax the condition of the matrices being square and of the same size, then take $A=(1,0)$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$. Then $AB=1$, while $BA=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @spiralstotheleft i guess that works but the original intention was determining if $A=B^{-1}$, which can't happen if they aren't square

Comment: I know. The example if for you to understand the role of the dimensions played in the proof.

Comment: @spiralstotheleft ok thanks